How can I find out how much parasitic drag will slow an object traveling vertically from a single impulse?
For my high school physics final I'm doing a project on the manhole cover launched vertically by a nuke from Project Plumbob and assuming it didn't melt in the atmosphere. How can I calculate the total amount it would get slowed by parasitic drag forces before it leaves the atmosphere? Assuming the cover is a 900kg flat circle 4ft in diameter with no skin drag with an initial velocity of 66,000m/s.

Parasitic drag might not be reasonable beyond a certain speed. To take it to extremes, you have to consider other things for a Relativistic Baseball. But you might start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitic_drag
